# Different color for a link

Tags: css

I have this:

```css
DIV#tt {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px;
}
DIV#tt A,
DIV#tt SPAN.link {
    color: #990000;
}
```

This works fine and changes the color of my links.

```
<div class="someotherclass"><span>My Link </span></a></div>
```

Now my issue is that there is a need when sometimes I want the color green instead.
How can I make that exception in the above CSS, and then call it in HTML?

Comment: and when and what is 'sometimes', please be more specific

Comment: That HTML is severely invalid - could you please fix it? It helps when understanding the question better.

Comment: @Autolycus -- you're missing the opening `<a>` tag in the HTML above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `div#tt a` selector indicates that all links (`<a>`) inside the `<div>` with the id `tt` should be styled in a particular way -- in this case, a color being set. So:

```
<div id="tt">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
</div>
<div id="abc">
    <a href="#">Link2</a>
</div>
```

In this example, Link 1 would be styled according to `div#tt a`, but Link 2 would not be.

Now, if you had Link 2 inside of the tt div, something like so

```
<div id="tt">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <div id="abc">
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then Link 2 *would* be styled the same as Link 1, as specified by the css for `div#tt a`. If you wanted different styling on Link 2, you'd need to apply a selector like `div#tt div#abc a`.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UEqKY/) for examples.

**EDIT**

If you want the two links on the same line, but styled differently, you could either surround the second link with a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`, which would not force a line break, or you could add an id to the second link.

Using a `<span>`, this is the HTML:

```
<div id="tt">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <span id="abc"><a href="#">Link 2</a></span>
</div>
```

Then you'd style the second link using `div#tt span#abc a`.

Alternatively, you could add an id to the second link and use that for styling. The HTML:

```
<div id="tt">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="two">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Then you'd style the links in general as `div#tt a` and the second link using `div#tt a#two`.

I've updated [the JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UEqKY/1/) to show the above.

**EDIT 2**

Per the comment below by F. Müller, whic is absolutely correct. I use id's a lot in the examples above, but it's probably better practice (especially if you want to style multiple links in the "secondary" style) to instead use other sorts of selectors.

For example, if you want Link 1 and Link 2 to be styled one way, and Link 3 and Link 4 to be styled another, this would be good HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="something">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="secondary">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="secondary">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

The styling would be:

```
div.something a {
    /* styling for primary links */
}
div.something a.secondary {
   /* styling for secondary links */
}
```

Here, if you wanted to add the secondary styling to more links, you'd just need to add the class name to the link. (That is, if you wanted to add a new Link 5, you'd just need to add `class="secondary"` to the `<a>` and it would be styled appropriately.)

And [the JSFiddle updated again](http://jsfiddle.net/UEqKY/2/) to show these changes.

Comment: yea but adding div will put it on next line. I want it in same line

Comment: You want the links side by side? Like `<a href="">A</a><a href="">B</a>`? @Autolycus

Comment: you could use float or span instead of divs

Comment: by the way it is good practice to set only the neccesairy ids - all the child elements can easyly be access by selectors ...

Comment: I stick Ids on everything. It's a side effect of working in an environment where all webpages are thoroughly tested with Selenium.

Comment: @F.Müller I've updated the answer to show examples using class names instead of explicit ids.

Comment: It is still overloaded. I rather meant: div.something > a:nth-child(1) or div.something > a:first-child() but it depends of course on the hierarchy - for me it's fine like it is now - and nth-child isn't that fast either - but at least it does what you exactly intended. And there are still classes out there.

Comment: `nth-child` would only work if you knew exactly which link in your hierarchy should be styled this way, which is why I like to avoid such styling as it's not dynamic. (What if you add a new link above it?) Other than `first-child` and `last-child`, I think the child selectors should be avoided.

Comment: As I said it depends on the hirarchy. I just want it to be mentionned. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use your class:

```css
#tt.someotherclass a, #tt.someotherclass span.link {
    color: green;
}
```